# Make a reserved word an identifier/variable in Lua?

Tags: lua

I want to make a reserved word (while, for, and, etc) a function variable. How could I do this?

Comment: As far as I know, Lua reserved words are case sensitive, so by using at least 1 uppercase letter they'll be treated as identifiers. "WHILE", "If", "fOR", etc. could all be used legally.

Answer (score 11):

Those words are reserved for a reason. You can't just turn them into variables. The only solution (if you want your code to look in a specific, yet wrong, way) is to modify them as for_ or for1, etc. There is no escape sequence to use in order to *unreserve* a previously reserved keyword.

Answer (score 3):

This will work, although it is discouraged.

```
_G["for"] = 42

print(_G["for"])
```

Edit to answer comment : As AdrianMar said, they are reserved for a reason. Plus, why do you want to do that ? It's very unlikely you have to. And finally, quoting the *Programming in Lua* book (Chapter 14) :

> Beware, however: some programmers get a little excited with these facilities and end up writing code like `_G["a"] = _G["var1"]`, which is just a complicated way to write `a = var1`.

Comment: Why is it strongly discouraged?

Comment: Ok, maybe not "strongly". I guess that if you absolutely have to do it, this is the way to go, but see my edit.

Answer (score -1):

Use a table instead. Probably with a short name.

```
x = {}
x.while = ...
x.for = ...

print(x.for)
```

EDIT: This will *NOT* work. Apologies.

Comment: This would not work in Lua, as `x = {}; x.for = ...` would result in error `stdin:1: '<name>' expected near 'for'`. A keyword is always a keyword in Lua, and you cannot use it as a field in this way. If you REALLY want to have a field called `end` or `for`, use the following syntax: `x["for"] = ...`, where you actually use the string `"for"`.

Comment: you are right. I should have tested this before answering. I'll leave my (wrong) answer up so others can avoid it.